# Negative rep from an answer being deleted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

Today I had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024836/156755) deleted by a mod (no argument over the deletion, it was an LMGTFY answer which needed to be deleted).

The answer has (had?) a score of -3

My Rep history for today shows -9 rep for that removal. I believed that rep from deleted downvoted questions/answers should be restored on a recalc. So I triggered a recalc.  My rep hasn't changed at all (that is, it's still 9 points lower than before the deletion).

I don't particularly care about the rep but would like to understand what happened here - Firstly, why did I get negative rep for the deletion and secondly why wasn't the negative rep (now deleted) re-credited?

Comment: I would suggest updating the answer to put the code there instead of in an external link, and possibly even explaining the code a bit. Then flag it for undeletion :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That post was the accepted answer, giving you +15 rep.  By being deleted it was automatically unaccepted, giving you -15 rep.  Since there were 3 downvotes, giving -6 rep, being reversed for +6, the end result is -15+6= -9 rep.  It is correct that you lost 9 rep as a result of the deletion.

Comment: I don't know if i like accepted answers getting deleted, unless there's' some sort of clear collusion

Comment: @SamIam There's no amount of acceptance by the OP that would make me not delete a LMGTFY link.

Comment: That must be it. Now it's deleted, I couldn't tell it had been the accepted answer (in fact, I think you've jogged my memory - I think that's why I couldn't delete it myself). And @Bill I completely agree - it was posted before I knew of that guideline.